# people who bring/brings you down

Tags: grammar

What should we use in the below sentence?

> **You should stop hanging with people who bring/brings you down and call/calls you stupid.**

I'm not sure if *people* here is plural or singular as it is used in a generic way. I would really appreciate, If somebody could help me out here.

I read about the single and plural uses of *people* on [this site](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00048.htm) but I'm still not clear on what to use here.

Comment: [*People*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/people) is plural. (*Person* is singular.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**People** can be used in a few ways, both are plural:

- **people** without an article just means some unspecified people: **...with people who bring you down and call you stupid"**
- **The people** is the population of a country considered as a body, often in political expressions like "The people are in favour of my policies."